# What percent of lighted grids are walkable: a trick-or-treating problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, puzzle, percolation

I am a math teacher that likes to invent fun math problems to explore. Here is one I have been investigating for a little while and have made little progress on because the number of possible $n \times n$ "grids" here is always $2^{n^2}$.

I imagine a kid trick-or-treating over a grid of houses on Halloween whose parents tell him he can only keep going so long as one house nearby has their lights on. Each house is either a lit or unlit square on a grid, which can be thought of as $n \times n$ for simplicity's sake, but $n \times m$ explorations are welcome also. The kid can start at any point in the grid, he does not have to begin on the edge. My question(s) are as follows:

1. Given an $n \times n$ grid, is there a closed form for the number of "walkable" grids? These are grids where the kid can get to every single house, meaning no house with its lights on is surrounded by houses with their lights off.
2. As $n \to \infty$, does the percentage of lighted grids that are walkable approach a non-zero value? (My gut feeling here is no, but it would be super cool if it did!)

Here is some information I do know:

For $2 \times 2$ grids, every one is walkable. For $3 \times 3$ grids, >50% are walkable, because if the middle house has its lights on, the grid is walkable no matter what.

For $n \times n$ grids where $n \geq 4$, a lower bound on the percentage of walkable grids is given by $\frac{100}{(n-2)^2}$ for similar reasons to $3 \times 3$ grids; if all the "middle" houses are lighted, the grid is automatically walkable.

If this is similar to another problem, please let me know, and if you find out anything cool here, awesome! This is my first post here, so hopefully this will at least spark some curiosity and exploration. I cannot write code very well, but imagine someone could brute force this for small integers for a little bit.

Edit: The kid can walk by the same house multiple times as long as it has its lights on. Only interested in visiting lit houses. "Walkable" if every lit house is within a king move of another lit house. Daniel Mathias had a worthwhile note simplifying the problem in the comments below, quoted, "...you have a grid of cells that are either 0 or 1 and you are asking what percentage of these grids have all of the 1's connected."

Comment: This is potentially an interesting question but it's not clear. It seems as if "walkable" means "visit all the lit houses" but that's not clear. How many houses are lit to start with? Are they lit independently with some probability?

Comment: I am hoping to find an answer for all possible numbers of lit houses for the grid, from 0 lit (always unwalkable) and 1 lit (always walkable) up to $n \times n$ lit (always walkable).

Comment: Related: [percolation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percolation_theory)

Comment: Still unclear whether visiting every house or every lit house. If the latter and there are no lit houses then the grid is walkable. If two lit houses that touch at a corner (not an edge) can you walk from one to the other? If yes you're asking about king moves. If no, then one step rook moves. Please [edit] to clarify, with more examples. Pictures would be good. In any case I think this is a really hard problem. See @Karl 's comment.

Comment: It would be helpful if you focused only on the mathematical properties of your question. There are no houses and no kids. You have a grid of cells that are either $0$ or $1$ and you are asking what percentage of these grids have all of the $1$'s connected.

Comment: A bit of brute force leads to OEIS entry [A286139](https://oeis.org/A286139)

Comment: For 2x2 grids, there are 16 possibilities out of which one is  No house is lit, then that grid is not walkable right? How come every 2x2 grid is walkable

Comment: bigstreet, you are correct, my fault. 15/16 of those are walkable, an unlit grid is unwalkable.

Comment: Daniel Mathias, thank you! I took the first few ratios of terms in that sequence and number of possible grids and got the ratios .9375, .7578, .5676, .4400, .3504, .2840, .2326, .1916, .1583, .1308... giving me little hope that this converges to a non-zero ratio for arbitrarily large grids. I could not find a closed form for that sequence, unsurprisingly, so the exploration continues for me! Thank you!

Comment: In a 2x2 grid, what if two houses on opposite corners are lit and the other two are unlit? Is that still walkable? If a kid starts at a lit house, the two adjacent houses are unlit. I'm not clear on what counts as a "nearby" house.

Comment: FYI, if you don't allow diagonal moves (no traipsing across lawns!) then the analogous OEIS entry is [A059525](https://oeis.org/A059525) - still no closed form, ratios decrease faster.

Comment: I wonder if it would help to refine this by number of lit houses. In the 3x3 grid, there can be 0 to 9 houses lit in 1, 9, 36, 84, 126, 126, 84, 36, 9, 1 ways, respectively. Of these, the number of walkable grids is 0, 9, 20, 48, 85, 102, 78, 36, 9, 1, respectively (these sum to the 388 in [A286139](https://oeis.org/A286139)).

Comment: It might make more sense to consider the unlit grid walkable, since there's nothing to visit.